# Springboot executable jar error using java -jar

Tags: maven, spring-boot, java-8

using command `/opt/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -jar webprx.jar` get this error: `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile webprx.jar`

jar was build with mvn clean package and mvn install

Pom

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `executable` configuration.

From the documentation this makes it executable by `*NIX` systems.

> Make a fully executable jar for *nix machines by prepending a launch script to the jar.
>
> Currently, some tools do not accept this format so you may not always
>   be able to use this technique. For example, jar -xf may silently fail
>   to extract a jar or war that has been made fully-executable. **It is
>   recommended that you only enable this option if you intend to execute
>   it directly, rather than running it with java -jar or deploying it to
>   a servlet container**.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html